# What to do when the client's cultural superstition is affecting ui-design desisions?

Tags: localization

I'm based in Taiwan. I was building a menu which has 4 sections:
home, projects, about and contact.

But the client refused to have 4 menus because the number 4 in Chinese (Sì), as the same sound as 'death.'

So at the end he just added a completely new section just to avoid having four menus.

What would you do in a case like this?

Comment: This similar to how how Arabs have navigation on the right and everyone else has navigation on the left? No one really questions this decision. As stupid as a cultural belief is, they're not going to give it up. So maybe you shouldn't question your client's cultural beliefs. Just add a 4th item or remove one item. I'm Taiwanese too and I've heard a lot of stupid things from my relatives, like when a woman is pregnant, she can't eat red bean soup (hone doe tong).

Comment: @JoJo I see, yeah finally I did that, but I'm still thinking that irrational beliefs shouldn't be mixed with technology (which is supposed to be based on logic).

Comment: If you tell your client not to mix superstition with design, he will fire you. I've been designing for stupid clients for a long time. From personal experience, it saves you pain and agony if you just do everything they want instead of trying to fight with them. Stupid people never listen. If you don't want to deal with bad design decisions, then you should consider designing for yourself - start your own website and make money somehow.

Comment: @JoJo is that what you did: http://www.veetle.com/? (You got tired of providing web design services to other people?)

Comment: I am a frontend developer on veetle.com. When working on your own website, there are still times when co-workers will suggest bad ideas. But I feel like there are more chances to fight back and have your voice heard. When doing freelance with random clients, they won't listen no matter how hard you fight back because they have a poor understanding of how the web works.

Comment: @JoJo Arabs don't have RTL navigation because it's a cultural belief, they have it because Arabic is an RTL language, and the navigation should be consistent with that. I seriously doubt that any cultural beliefs exist specifically with regard to  website navigation :)

Comment: The RTL langauge is part of their culture.

Comment: @JoJo - it has nothing to do with a cultural belief. That language is read that way. They don't read right-to-left when they are reading English, do they? If it was a cultural thing, and not a language-specific thing, then they would *always* be reading from right to left.

Comment: Does Chinese cars usually have 3 or 5 wheels to avoid this? ...or perhaps it's fitting for such a dangerous machine to have "death wheels" ;) Superstition about such a low number must be complicated...

Comment: @Stein G. Strindhaug hah that was a good one.

Comment: As stupid as the superstition is, the client might not be that stupid in requesting it. I'm not too sure about Taiwan, but at least in mainland China, some people take the 4 thing pretty seriously, so even if your client didn't request this, some of your client's users might get similarily vexed by the 4. Though... I do have to admit, this is a bit of an extreme case. I have frequently heard of people abstaining from using the number 4 explicitly or skipping 4 when numbering things, but avoiding having 4 items on a menu is a bit absurd.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, I would blog about it :). This is a gem, and I don't mean it in a derogatory way, it really is a beautiful case.

And in more practical terms - benchmarking. Look at other chinese websites, see how they solve this issue. I know that chinese elevators say 1-2-3-3A-5, or alternatively 1-2-3-5-6. This is not a solution in this case, since your problem is not with the numbering, but it shows that this is a very common problem and it must've been addressed somewhere.

Five sections is not too much, but if you feel that the extra section is unjustified, you can try combining Projects and Home, or About and Contact (which probably makes more sense). I'm talking about combining the content of the two pages, not adding another level of hierarchy, which would add unnecessary complexity.

Another solution - make the Contact title an icon, so it doesn't seem to be of the same kind as the first three items. Or come up with another visual differentiation, making it 3+1 and not 4. Maybe just separate it - if it's a horizontal navigation bar and the first three are on the left, move the Contact to the right, or some other grouping trick. If it's a vertical menu, maybe a divider will be enough.

Comment: Thanks, they are very good solutions (I wonder if the client will faint if I use the color `#444` as branding color).

Comment: @janoChen +1 because you made me laugh!